# Error processing package Likewise-open

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

whenever I try updating/upgrading/installing I get this:

```
Setting up likewise-open (6.1.0.406-0ubuntu5) ...
Error: /usr/sbin/lwsmd --start-as-daemon returned 1 (aborting this script)
dpkg: error processing package likewise-open (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 likewise-open
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

likwwise-open has been rebranded, and removed from official repositories. It is now known as BeyondTrust PowerBroker Identity Services, Open Edition . check [this](http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True).

Now to solve your problem remove the likewise-open package

```
sudo apt-get remove likewise-open
```

And then install the PowerBroker

Download the PowerBroker Identity Services, Open Edition installer for your type of computer and operating system from the list and then make it executable with chmod a+x. Or, right-click the installer, click Properties, click the Permissions tab, select Execute for Owner, and then click Close. Then double-click the installer to run it.

After installing PowerBroker Identity Services, Open Edition, run the following command as root. Your AD account must have privileges to join computers to the domain:

```
 /opt/pbis/bin/domainjoin-cli join domainName ADjoinAccount
```

Log on with your AD credentials by using the form DOMAIN\username. On the command line, you must include an escape character: `DOMAIN\\username`.